# how to connect powerbuilder to oracle with jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, powerbuilder, ojdbc, oracle19c

I'm using oracle 19c and I want to connect from Powerbuilder 12.0 with jdbc. I got this error[image]

Does anybody have any insight into this problem?

thanks

Comment: Have you verified that you have ojdbc8.jar (from 19c) in your classpath?

Comment: i have verified ojdbc on classpath, can you show me how? maybe my way is wrong

Comment: Contradictory.  First you say "i _have verified_ ojdbc on classpath"  (emphasis mine).  Then you ask "can you show me how?"  If you don't know how, then how did you verify?  ("I have verified")?    It's an environment variable.  echo %CLASSPATH%.